# How to identify cmd failures when submitting cmds in parallel?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am submitting multiple cmds in parallel as below,to figure out if any of the cmds failed I parse the `submissionsresults_list` which sometimes fails as the parsing strings can change or a new error string can pop up,is
there a way to use the cmds return code to figure out for sure if any cmd has failed?

```
def function_create_cmds(cmd):
    logger.info('%s'%cmd)
    print(repr(shlex.split(cmd)))
    proc = Popen(shlex.split(cmd), stdin=PIPE,stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    #proc = Popen(cmd.split(' '), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
    (output, error) = proc.communicate()
    return output,error


    cmds = ['cmd1','cmd2','cmd3','cmd4']
    pool = ThreadPool(len(cmds))
    submissionsresults_list = pool.map(function_create_cmds, cmds)

    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Examine the `returncode` attribute?

Comment: how do we do that for parallel commands?`submissionsresults_list` will only give me the output and error for each of the cmd

Comment: It supplies that information just because that’s what you return from `function_create_cmds`!

Comment: @DavisHerring - I dont see return code being returned from `function_create_cmds`,it only returns the output and error

Comment: So change that?

Comment: how exactly to get the return code?

Comment: I answered that in the first comment!